# This is not the correct coordinator for this group kafka error

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafkajs

I am using kafkajs and getting this error

```
{"level":"INFO","timestamp":"2022-07-07T08:55:41.859Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Consumer] Starting","groupId":"ReplacerService_9f1296ad-d028-4812-a84f-81cf2743640f"}

{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2022-07-07T08:55:49.414Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Consumer] Crash: KafkaJSNumberOfRetriesExceeded: This is not the correct coordinator for this group","groupId":"ReplacerService_9f1296ad-d028-4812-a84f-81cf2743640f","retryCount":5,"stack":"KafkaJSNonRetriableError\n  Caused by: KafkaJSError: This is not the correct coordinator for this group\n    at C:\\Users\\wgupta\\Backend\\AI\\service\\node_modules\\kafkajs\\src\\consumer\\consumerGroup.js:361:17\n    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n 
 at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)\n    at async Runner.start
```

I am not able to figure out what is the issue `This is not the correct coordinator for this group`

Broker value - `KAFKA_BROKERS="localhost:9092"`

Comment: How did you install Kafka?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the problem is with logs folder (where meta.properties is stored)
So before I launch zookeeper then kafka, I fully empty logs folder. To have everything in one place I just have one bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf /home/kafka/logs
mkdir /home/kafka/logs
sudo systemctl start zookeeper
sudo systemctl start kafka
```

Comment: Doesn't this reset all topic data?

Comment: I belieave it shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

For mac OSX, The logs had to be cleared and given right permissions. This logs path is logs.dir in /opt/homebrew/etc/kafka/server.properties

```
rm -rf /opt/homebrew/var/lib/kafka-logs
mkdir /opt/homebrew/var/lib/kafka-logs
chmod 777 /opt/homebrew/var/lib/kafka-logs
```

Then restart the zookeeper and kafka